# I want to restart a form but not restart Application?

Tags: vb.net

I just create an application but I want to restart a form in Application without re-click open form or restart application.

Comment: There's no such thing as restarting a form.  If you want to show a form then show a form.  If you want to close a form, close it.  If you want to close a form and show another form of the same type, do that.  If you want to reset an open form to the state it was in when it was opened then there's no magic way to do that; you just have to write code to change the state.

Comment: Thanks You But Now I can do it

Comment: Is that a question and you meant to ask "how" or was it a statement?  If it was a question then forget it.  I've told you what to do.  If you don't know how to show and close forms or change the contents of controls then read a beginners tutorial.  We're not here to teach you the fundamentals but to help with specific issues with code you've written.  If you haven't written any code then you haven't encountered an issue yet.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
If "check some condition" Then
    Dim frm = New Form1               
    frm.Show()
    Me.Close()
End If
```

Comment: This will cause problems for any other forms trying to access the original form.